# Создать DataFrame с десятью столбцами из списка с 1150 элементами

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Имеется список из 1150 элементов и готовый датафрейм с 10 столбцами. Необходимо вбить 1-ый, 11-ый, 21-ый, и так далее элемент в первый столбец датафрейма; 2-ой, 12-ый и тд во второй столбец, аналогично с остальными элементами.

```
data = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']) #готовый датафрейм

resultlist = ['71', '45', '18', '77', '64', 'Moy', '12', '92', '21' ...] #список
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

После преобразования списка в Numpy array, его можно легко трансформировать в 2D матрицу с десятью столбцами:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

In [32]: lst = list(range(1, 1151))

In [33]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(lst).reshape(-1, 10))

In [34]: df
Out[34]:
        0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
0       1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
1      11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20
2      21    22    23    24    25    26    27    28    29    30
3      31    32    33    34    35    36    37    38    39    40
4      41    42    43    44    45    46    47    48    49    50
5      51    52    53    54    55    56    57    58    59    60
6      61    62    63    64    65    66    67    68    69    70
7      71    72    73    74    75    76    77    78    79    80
8      81    82    83    84    85    86    87    88    89    90
9      91    92    93    94    95    96    97    98    99   100
..    ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...
105  1051  1052  1053  1054  1055  1056  1057  1058  1059  1060
106  1061  1062  1063  1064  1065  1066  1067  1068  1069  1070
107  1071  1072  1073  1074  1075  1076  1077  1078  1079  1080
108  1081  1082  1083  1084  1085  1086  1087  1088  1089  1090
109  1091  1092  1093  1094  1095  1096  1097  1098  1099  1100
110  1101  1102  1103  1104  1105  1106  1107  1108  1109  1110
111  1111  1112  1113  1114  1115  1116  1117  1118  1119  1120
112  1121  1122  1123  1124  1125  1126  1127  1128  1129  1130
113  1131  1132  1133  1134  1135  1136  1137  1138  1139  1140
114  1141  1142  1143  1144  1145  1146  1147  1148  1149  1150

[115 rows x 10 columns]
```

---

**UPDATE:**

```
In [38]: data = pd.DataFrame(np.array(lst).reshape(-1, 10), columns=data.columns)

In [39]: data
Out[39]:
        0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
0       1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
1      11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20
2      21    22    23    24    25    26    27    28    29    30
3      31    32    33    34    35    36    37    38    39    40
4      41    42    43    44    45    46    47    48    49    50
5      51    52    53    54    55    56    57    58    59    60
6      61    62    63    64    65    66    67    68    69    70
7      71    72    73    74    75    76    77    78    79    80
8      81    82    83    84    85    86    87    88    89    90
9      91    92    93    94    95    96    97    98    99   100
..    ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...
105  1051  1052  1053  1054  1055  1056  1057  1058  1059  1060
106  1061  1062  1063  1064  1065  1066  1067  1068  1069  1070
107  1071  1072  1073  1074  1075  1076  1077  1078  1079  1080
108  1081  1082  1083  1084  1085  1086  1087  1088  1089  1090
109  1091  1092  1093  1094  1095  1096  1097  1098  1099  1100
110  1101  1102  1103  1104  1105  1106  1107  1108  1109  1110
111  1111  1112  1113  1114  1115  1116  1117  1118  1119  1120
112  1121  1122  1123  1124  1125  1126  1127  1128  1129  1130
113  1131  1132  1133  1134  1135  1136  1137  1138  1139  1140
114  1141  1142  1143  1144  1145  1146  1147  1148  1149  1150

[115 rows x 10 columns]

In [40]: data.columns
Out[40]: Index(['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, вы создаете новый датафрейм, а мне необходимо именно вбить в уже готовый. (просто так необходимо)

Comment: @ПупкинПутя, "готовый DataFrame" пустой?

Comment: @ MaxU Да, пустой

Comment: @ПупкинПутя, смотрите UPDATE